# Table header name with checkbox

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, datatables, vue-component

Can anyone help me? I have created a table with checkbox. but I keep losing the table header name because it was being replaced by the checkbox. The first column with checkbox should be Notify Me and the other is Email Me. How can I put those header names together with the checkbox? here is the code that I have created:

```
<template>
    <Modal @close="doClose">
        <template v-slot:container>
            <section class="card settings-vue-modal-container">
                <header class="card-header">
                    <h2>Settings</h2>
                    <!-- <span class="custom-close fa fa-times" @click="doClose"></span> -->
                </header>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class='table-design'>
                        <SimpleDatatable
                            :init_data="tableData"
                            :init_columns="columns"
                            :init_is_loading="isTableLoading"
                            :isColumnCustomizable="false"
                            :isBoredered="true"
                            :isTableHeaderSticky="true"
                            :removeBorderWrapper="true"
                            :showTotalResult="false"
                            tableContentClass="users-table-content"
                            @changePage="changePage"
                            @getTableData="setTableData"
                            @getSelectedData="getSelectedData"
                        >
                        </SimpleDatatable>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <footer class="card-footer">
                    <div class="btn-group ml-auto float-right">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-close" @click="doClose">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </footer>
            </section>
        </template>
    </Modal>
</template>

<script>
import Modal from "../Reusable/Modal"
import SimpleDatatable from '../Others/SimpleDatatable';

export default {
    components: {
        Modal,
        SimpleDatatable
    },

    data() {
        return {
            settingsData: [],
            isTableLoading: false,
            params: {
                page: this.currentPage,
                page_limit: 10,
                search: '',
                role: ''
            },
            columns: [
                {
                    label: 'Task Schedule',
                    field: 'name',
                    align: 'center',
                    default: true
                },
                {
                    label: 'Notify Me',
                    type: 'checkbox',
                    align: 'center',
                    width: 200
                },
                {
                    label: 'Email Me',
                    type: 'checkbox',
                    align: 'center',
                    width: 200
                }
            ],
            tableData: {},
            currentPage: 1,
            selectedData: [],
            requiredData: {},
            errors: {},
            name: '',
        };
    },

    created() {
        this.getTableData()
    },

    watch: {
        currentPage(newValue, oldValue) {
            this.params.page = newValue
            this.getTableData()
        }
    },

    methods: {
        doClose() {
            this.errors = {};
            this.name = '';
            this.$emit('close');
        },

        changePage(event) {
            this.currentPage = event
        },

        setTableData(data) {
            this.tableData = data
        },

        getSelectedData(data) {
            this.selectedData = data.map(x => x.id)
        },

        getTableData() {
            this.isTableLoading = true
            let url = '/tasks/api/getAll'

            axios
                .post(url, this.params)
                .then(response => {
                    this.setTableData(response.data)
                    this.isTableLoading = false
                })
                .catch(errors => {
                    this.isTableLoading = false
                    console.log(errors)
                })
        },
    }
}
</script>
```

Thank you. Below is also the SimpleDatatable being used:

```
<template>
  <div class="row">
    <SeeMore
      :content="this.seeMoreContent"
      v-show="seeMoreModalVisibility"
      @close="seeMoreModalVisibility=false"
    />
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <CustomizeColumnModal
        v-show="showColumnModal"
        @close="showColumnModal = false"
        :columns="init_columns"
        @getCols="getColumn"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div
        class="panel panel-default"
        style="margin-bottom: 0"
        :class="{ 'no-border': removeBorderWrapper }"
      >
        <div
          class="panel-body"
          style="margin-bottom: 0"
          :class="{ 'no-border': removeBorderWrapper }"
        >
          <loading :active.sync="isLoading" :is-full-page="fullPage" style="z-index: 3;"></loading>
          <div class="pull-left">
            <slot name="functional_upper_left"></slot>
            <b
              class="ml-3"
              v-if="data.total && showTotalResult && totalResultPosition === 'upperLeft' "
            >Total Result: {{data.total | addComma }}</b>
          </div>
          <button
            class="btn btn-lg btn-primary pull-right"
            v-if="isColumnCustomizable"
            @click="showColumnModal = true"
            style="margin-bottom: 15px;"
          >
            <span class="fa fa-list" style=" margin-right: 5px;"></span> Columns
          </button>
          <slot name="functional_buttons"></slot>
          <div class="table table-responsive" style="overflow: auto; max-height: 550px;">
            <table
              class="table table-hover table-striped"
              :class="{ 'table-bordered': isBoredered }"
              style="margin-bottom: 0"
            >
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th
                    v-for="(col, index) in columns"
                    :class="{'amzentrix-th-sticky' : isTableHeaderSticky, 'with-select-dropdown': col.type === 'checkbox' && isSelectOptions }"
                    :key="index"
                    :style="{ minWidth: (col.width) ? `${col.width}px`: '100px', textAlign: (col.align) ? `${col.align}` : 'left' }"
                  >
                    <template v-if="col.type === 'checkbox'">
                      <div class="dropdown">
                        <input type="checkbox" @click="doSelectAll" v-model="isSelectAll" />
                        <a
                          class="dropdown-toggle"
                          id="dropdownSelectOptions"
                          data-toggle="dropdown"
                          aria-haspopup="true"
                          aria-expanded="false"
                          v-if="isSelectOptions"
                        />
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownSelectOptions">
                          <span class="dropdown-item" @click="doSelectAllOnly">Select All</span>
                          <span class="dropdown-item" @click="doSelectTop(10)">Select Top 10</span>
                          <span class="dropdown-item" @click="doSelectTop(20)">Select Top 20</span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </template>
                    <template v-else-if="col.sortable">
                      <div class="sortable_col" @click="sortCol(index)">
                        <span>{{ col.label }}</span>
                        <span class="sortable_icons">
                          <i class="fa fa-sort-up" :class="{ active: col.currentSort === 'ASC'}" />
                          <i
                            class="fa fa-sort-down"
                            :class="{ active: col.currentSort === 'DESC'}"
                          />
                        </span>
                      </div>
                    </template>
                    <template v-else>{{ col.label }}</template>
                  </th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody v-if="data.total !== 0">
                <template v-for="(row, index) in data.data">
                  <tr :key="index">
                    <td
                      v-for="(col, index) in columns"
                      :class="tableContentClass"
                      :style="{
                                                textAlign: (col.align) ? `${col.align}` : 'left',
                                                'vertical-align': (col.valign) ? col.valign : 'middle' 
                                            }"
                      :key="index"
                    >
                      <template v-if="col.type == 'checkbox' ">
                        <div class="vue-checkbox">
                          <input
                            type="checkbox"
                            :checked="row.selected"
                            @click="doSelect(row, $event)"
                          />
                        </div>
                      </template>
                      <template v-else-if="col.type === 'action'">
                        <slot :name="`action-${row.id}`">
                          <slot name="action" :data="row" />
                        </slot>
                      </template>
                      <template v-else-if="col.type == 'date'">{{ timeHumanize(row[col.field]) }}</template>
                      <template
                        v-else-if="col.type == 'complete_date'"
                      >{{ completeDateFormat(row[col.field]) }}</template>
                      <template v-else-if="col.type == 'raw'">
                        <div v-html="row[col.field]"></div>
                      </template>
                      <template v-else-if="col.type == 'rounded_numbers'">
                        <div>{{ row[col.field] ? Number(row[col.field]).toFixed(4) : row[col.field] }}</div>
                      </template>
                      <template
                        v-else-if="col.type == 'status'"
                      >{{ row[col.field] ? 'Active': 'Inactive' }}</template>
                      <template v-else-if="col.type == 'more'">
                        <div v-if="row[col.field]">
                          <p v-html="seeMoreTexts(row[col.field].replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, ''))"></p>
                          <small
                            class="see-more"
                            @click="seeMore(row[col.field])"
                            v-if="row[col.field].length> 20"
                          >See More</small>
                        </div>
                        <p v-else>-</p>
                        <!-- {{ row[col.field] ? '<h1>awit</h1>' : '-' }} -->
                      </template>
                      <template v-else-if="col.type == 'field_value'">
                        <slot name="field_value" :data="row"></slot>
                      </template>
                      <template v-else>{{ row[col.field] ? row[col.field] : '-' }}</template>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </template>
              </tbody>
              <tbody v-else>
                <tr>
                  <td align="center" colspan="1000">
                    <slot name="no-result">
                      <span style="margin-right: 5px">No Data Found.</span>
                    </slot>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>

          <!-- PAGINATION -->
          <nav v-if="data.total && data.total !== 0 && !data.single">
            <ul class="pagination" :class="`float-${paginationPosition}`">
              <li
                class="page-item pagination-total-result px-3"
                v-if="data.total && showTotalResult && totalResultPosition === 'bottomPaginationLeftSide'"
              >
                Total Result:
                <b class="ml-2">{{data.total | addComma }}</b>
              </li>
              <slot name="pagination-left" />
              <li class="page-item pr-3 page-limit-select" v-if="isCustomResultPerPage">
                <label for="results-per-page">Results per page:</label>
                <input
                  class="form-control"
                  id="results-per-page"
                  type="number"
                  min="1"
                  @change="handleChangeItemsPerPage"
                  v-model="page_limit"
                />
              </li>
              <li
                class="page-item"
                :class=" data.current_page <= 1 ? 'disabled' : '' "
                @click=" changePage((data.current_page - 1))"
              >
                <a
                  class="page-link"
                  :href=" (data.current_page > 1) ? `#page-${data.current_page - 1}` : `#page-1`"
                  aria-label="Previous"
                >
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                  <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li
                class="page-item"
                v-for="(n, index) in pagination(data.current_page, data.last_page)"
                :class="(n === data.current_page) ? 'active' : ''"
                :key="index"
                @click="changePage(n)"
              >
                <a class="page-link" :href="(typeof n == 'number') ? `#page-${n}` : '#' ">{{ n }}</a>
              </li>
              <li
                class="page-item"
                :class=" data.current_page >= data.last_page ? 'disabled' : '' "
                @click=" changePage((data.current_page + 1))"
              >
                <a
                  class="page-link"
                  :href=" (data.current_page < data.last_page) ? `#page-${data.current_page + 1}` : `#page-${data.last_page}`"
                  aria-label="Next"
                >
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                  <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <slot name="pagination-right" />
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<style scoped src='bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'></style>
<script>
import moment from "moment";
import CustomizeColumnModal from "./Datatable/CustomizeColumn";
import SeeMore from "./SimpleDatatableModal";
export default {
  components: {
    CustomizeColumnModal,
    SeeMore
  },
  props: {
    init_data: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
    },
    init_columns: {
      type: Array,
      required: true
    },
    init_is_loading: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    },
    init_page_limit: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0
    },
    isSelectOptions: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    },
    isColumnCustomizable: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    },
    isBoredered: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    },
    isTableHeaderSticky: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    },
    isCustomResultPerPage: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    },
    removeBorderWrapper: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    },
    showTotalResult: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    },
    totalResultPosition: {
      type: String,
      default: "upperLeft"
    },
    tableContentClass: {
      type: String,
      default: ""
    },
    paginationPosition: {
      type: String,
      default: "left"
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      data: { total: 0 },
      columns: this.init_columns,
      isLoading: this.init_is_loading,
      fullPage: false,
      isSelectAll: false,
      showColumnModal: false,
      seeMoreContent: "",
      seeMoreModalVisibility: false,
      page_limit: this.init_page_limit
    };
  },
  watch: {
    init_data(newData, oldData) {
      this.data = newData;
      this.isSelectAll = false;
      if (this.isSelectOptions) {
        this.getSelectedData();
      }
    },
    init_is_loading(newData, oldData) {
      this.isLoading = newData;
      if (this.isSelectOptions) {
        this.checkSelectHeaderModel(); //Will reset isSelectAll State. Important if you're using checkbox and with dynamic data.
      }
    },
    init_columns(newCols) {
      this.columns = newCols;
    },
    init_page_limit(newData) {
      this.page_limit = newData;
    }
  },
  filters: {
    addComma(value) {
      return value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    }
  },
  methods: {
    resetSortColFields() {
      const withSortColFields = this.columns.filter(col => col.currentSort);
      const resetColFields = withSortColFields.map(col => {
        col.currentSort = null;
        return col;
      });
    },
    //returns an object with sortType (eg. ASC or DESC ) and field (eg. DATE, ID)
    sortCol(index) {
      const { currentSort } = this.columns[index];
      let sort = null;

      this.resetSortColFields();

      switch (currentSort) {
        case "ASC":
          sort = null;
          break;
        case "DESC":
          sort = "ASC";
          break;
        default:
          sort = "DESC";
      }

      this.columns[index].currentSort = sort;

      this.$emit("sort", {
        sortType: sort,
        field: sort ? this.columns[index].field : null
      });
    },
    doSelectAll(event) {
      //single property for single set of data, means no paginated data.
      //usually you want to use this if you're not using primarily the api of laravel's pagination.
      //you just need to pass an initial object data with data and single properties
      if (!this.data.total && !this.data.single) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return;
      }

      this.isSelectAll = !this.isSelectAll;
      this.data.data.forEach(element => {
        element.selected = this.isSelectAll;
      });
      if (!this.isSelectAll) this.$emit("getDeselectedData", this.data.data);
      this.$emit("getTableData", this.data);
      this.getSelectedData();
    },
    doSelectAllOnly() {
      if (!this.isSelectAll) this.doSelectAll();
    },
    doSelectTop(num) {
      this.data.data.forEach((element, index) => {
        if (num > index) element.selected = true;
      });
      this.getSelectedData();
    },
    checkSelectHeaderModel() {
      // to check if all data from the data is selected, if true, checkbox from header must be checked.
      if (!this.data.data) return;
      const newDataLength = this.data.data.length;
      const newSelectedDataLength = this.data.data.filter(data => data.selected)
        .length;
      this.isSelectAll =
        newDataLength && newDataLength === newSelectedDataLength ? true : false;
    },
    doSelect(row, event) {
      let checked = Boolean(row.selected);
      row.selected = !checked;
      if (!row.selected) {
        this.$emit("getDeselectedItem", row);
      }
      this.getSelectedData();
    },
    getSelectedData() {
      const selected = this.data.data.filter(el => el.selected);
      this.checkSelectHeaderModel();
      this.$emit("getSelectedData", selected);
    },
    getColumn(event) {
      if (this.isColumnCustomizable) {
        this.columns = event;
        this.$emit("getSelectedColumns", event);
      }
    },
    timeHumanize(date) {
      return moment(date).isValid() ? moment(date).fromNow() : date;
    },
    completeDateFormat(date) {
      return moment(date).isValid()
        ? moment(date).format("MMM Do YYYY h:mm:ss a")
        : date;
    },
    changePage(pageNumber) {
      this.handleChangeItemsPerPage();
      if (
        pageNumber > 0 &&
        pageNumber <= this.data.last_page &&
        typeof pageNumber == "number" &&
        this.data.current_page != pageNumber
      )
        this.$emit("changePage", pageNumber);
    },
    pagination(c, m) {
      let current = c,
        last = m,
        delta = 3,
        left = current - delta,
        right = current + delta + 1,
        range = [],
        rangeWithDots = [],
        l;

      for (let i = 1; i <= last; i++) {
        if (i == 1 || i == last || (i >= left && i < right)) {
          range.push(i);
        }
      }

      for (let i of range) {
        if (l) {
          if (i - l === 2) {
            rangeWithDots.push(l + 1);
          } else if (i - l !== 1) {
            rangeWithDots.push("...");
          }
        }
        rangeWithDots.push(i);
        l = i;
      }

      return rangeWithDots;
    },
    seeMoreTexts(text) {
      return text.length > 20 ? text.substring(0, 40) + "..." : text;
    },
    seeMore(data) {
      this.seeMoreContent = data;
      this.seeMoreModalVisibility = true;
    },
    handleChangeItemsPerPage(event) {
      let value;
      let changePage = false;
      if (typeof event == "object") {
        value = parseInt(event.target.value);
        changePage = true;
      } else {
        value = parseInt(this.page_limit);
      }
      if (value <= 0 || typeof value != "number" || !value) {
        value = 10;
        this.page_limit = 10;
      }
      this.$emit("handleChangeItemsPerPage", parseInt(value), changePage);
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    //single property for single set of data, means no paginated data.
    //usually you want to use this if you're not using primarily the api of laravel's pagination.
    //you just need to pass an initial object data with data and single properties
    this.data =
      this.init_data.total || this.init_data.single
        ? this.init_data
        : { total: 0 };
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: The problem probably depends on the implementation of `SimpleDatatable`. What are you using for it? Can you provide a reproduction in Codesandbox?

Comment: @tony19 hi tony. I am just trying to uniform my codes to what was done also to other pages. I'll try to edit my question and include the SimpleDatatable. It's kinda long though

Comment: @tony19 I already added the SimpleDatatable here also. I believe I can add up my own codes here for me to achieve what I want? But not sure how do edit this. I might break the codes